# How to add a tooltip (image) to a button?

Tags: java, javafx

How to add tooltip (i button in image) in javafx.[image]

```
                final Label response = new Label();
                final ImageView imageViews = new ImageView(
                        new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/desktop-buffet/128/Pizza-icon.png"));
                final Button buttons = new Button("test", imageViews);
                buttons.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        response.setText("test");
                    }
                });

                buttons.getStyleClass().add("button1");
```

Comment: .... no, thats not how you do it, try again.

Comment: Don't post your code in the comments. [Edit] the question instead.

Comment: Thats also not how you do it. I think you should'nt post how-to's if you dont even actually know how to do it ... just sayian ... maybe try asking for help, first

Comment: so, what's the question?

Comment: how to show this.......i button in javafx.clicking it show some informative message

Comment: just a friendly advice : if you want to get into programming, you will **need** to train your english-skills. Verily. Its not actually possible to write code without advanced language skills - well you *could* try to write everything yourself and rely on code with comments and nomenclatures in your own language but thats ... unrealistic. Do language courses for english - all of them. The IT world got used to english, its pretty much a standard language and literally every professional uses it.

Comment: HAHAHA......i button in javafx(it means informative button).I now understood the grammatical change .Any way thank you for your valuable advice

Comment: .... what? Your sentences dont make much sense ... could you please ask someone to help you translate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is code for a [Tooltip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html) with an Image:

```
Image image = new Image(IMAGE_LOC);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
tooltip.setGraphic(imageView);
button.setTooltip(tooltip);
```

Though, in looking at your image mockup, the highlighted areas don't really look like a Tooltip at all.  It seems like what you want instead is an image or button that somebody could click on to get more information.  You can do that using a standard button with a graphic in it:

```
Image image = new Image(IMAGE_LOC);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
Button button = new Button();
button.setGraphic(imageView);
button.setOnAction(event -> showInfoPopup());
```

You can [style](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm) the resultant button using CSS to get the style you wish.  The `showInfoPopup()` method in the above code is some code which you write to show the information message you wish.

Or you can just create a clickable [ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html):

```
Image image = new Image(IMAGE_LOC);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
Glow glow = new Glow();
imageView.effectProperty().bind(
    Bindings.when(imageView.hoverProperty()).then(glow).otherwise(null)
);
imageView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> showInfoPopup());
```